# Auto Layout with navigation bar and view controller (iOS 7)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm currently transiting my application to iOS 7 (I want it to remain iOS 6 compatible). This question is not covered by the Apple NDA, it is a question about Auto Layout (it seems that iOS 7 forces Auto Layout (EDIT : was wrong, it is not forced)).

I have a navigation controller with a root view controller (obvious). With iOS 6, i was not using Auto Layout, so the root view controllers was below the navigation bar. With iOS 7, the frame origin does not include the navigation bar, so the top part of my content is hidden...

Have you an idea how to make the entire view above the navigation bar with Auto Layout ?

Thanks !

Comment: I may be wrong but I'd be surprised if Apple "forced" developers to use auto layout in iOS7? Is this definitely the case? (this information may be covered by the NDA!)

Comment: Autolayout is not forced in iOS 7. It is improved.

Comment: Its is forced. they didn't mentioned in the doc. Check the frame values before viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear . I don't use IB but still values differ .. What does this suggest ?? !!

Comment: http://www.mobilityeffect.com/mobility-effect-s/the-impact-of-ios-7-5-increased-emphasis-on-auto-layout for details

Comment: It is NOT forced. It's incredibly easy to turn it off. Same as iOS 6, in the Identity Inspector, uncheck "Use Autolayout".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On iOS 7 you have the topLayoutGuide that specify the navigation bar. You can then specify that you want that the constraint of the tableview is on the topLayoutGuide and not the superview.

This will help you to know if it's iOS7 or not:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(topLayoutGuide)])
```

So it can be something like that

```
NSString *verticalConstraint = @"V:|[v]|";
NSMutableDictionary *views = [NSMutableDictionary new];
views[@"v"] = self.tableview;
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(topLayoutGuide)]) {
    views[@"topLayoutGuide"] = self.topLayoutGuide;
    verticalConstraint = @"V:[topLayoutGuide][v]|";
}
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:verticalConstraint options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

Comment: to compile on ios 6, self.topLayoutGuide need to be [self valueForKey:@"topLayoutGuide"] (tested on iOS 7 GM)

Comment: @kschaeffler would you mind explaining the syntax behind @"V:[topLayoutGuide][v]|"?  I'm going through the article on visual format languages, but I'm still a tad bit confused.  I think it's saying that Vertical is related to the topLayoutGuide, but...  Edit:  *Flash -- lightbulb goes off*  Nevermind, I think I understand.  The starting V: says you're setting up a vertical layout, and then [object1][object2] is saying that objects 1 and 2 are flush -- right against each other.  Just not sure what the | does.

Comment: OK, since I figured it out myself, I'll just post a quick explanation:  the 'V: ' part modifies this so that you're effecting vertical layout.  The [topLayoutGuide] acts as a reference to the top layout guide provided by the view, which is placed flush against the subview, represented by [v].  The closing pipe means the edge of the view is flush with the end of the superview.  Once understood, a very clear and beautiful layout language... if hard to understand at first.

Comment: @RonLugge you have all the information about visual format in the apple documentation :) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/formatLanguage.html

Comment: @kschaeffler The information is there, but the presentation is lacking.  Just as an example, going through it repeatedly, I couldn't figure out how [button] was referencing the button, except maybe as some kind of magic constant.  It wasn't until I also went through the class documentation that I began to understand.

Comment: `NSMutableDictionary *views = [NSMutableDictionary new];
views[@"v"] = self.tableview;`
You can see here that I declare a mutable dictionary. This dictionary will help me to define those `[v]` and `[topLayoutGuide]` when I add the constraint using this function `[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:verticalConstraint options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];`
the views parameter is the mutableDictionary that will make the reference to the views. Sorry to not have been clear enough before :)

Comment: According to the transition guide you can set a constraint to the toplayout guide in the interface builder. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @shim you can only do this in storyboard not XIB. Very annoying!

Comment: @Morgz yes, it is pretty annoying. But using Storyboards is generally a lot easier, so I try to use them whenever possible.