# What is replacement of iOS7 LayoutGuide in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios6

I am using EMCCountryPickerController ( https://github.com/emcrisostomo/EMCCountryPickerController ) for Country Picker  in app  Development. It is working good in iOS7. But it crashed because of LayoutGuide which is not available in iOS6. I am not sure how to change this code to work in iOS6.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self validateSettings];
    [self loadCountries];

    [rootView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:searchBar
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:self.topLayoutGuide
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                        multiplier:1
                                                          constant:0]];

    [rootView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:searchBar
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:rootView
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                        multiplier:1
                                                          constant:0]];

    [rootView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:searchBar
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:rootView
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                        multiplier:1
                                                          constant:0]];

    [rootView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:countryTable
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:searchBar
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                        multiplier:1
                                                          constant:0]];

    [rootView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rootView
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:countryTable
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                        multiplier:1
                                                          constant:0]];

    [rootView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rootView
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:countryTable
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                        multiplier:1
                                                          constant:0]];

    [rootView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.bottomLayoutGuide
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:countryTable
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                        multiplier:1
                                                          constant:0]];

}
```

Comment: "This library has been built with XCode 5.1.1 using iOS 7.1 as a build target. This library requires iOS >= 7." You may find there are further problems down the line than this.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18741582/1032151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in both iOS 6.1 & 7 after replacing self.topLayoutGuide & self.bottomLayoutGuide with self.view.

> ```
> if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
>     [rootView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:searchBar
>                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
>                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
>                                                             toItem:self.topLayoutGuide
>                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
>                                                         multiplier:1
>                                                           constant:0]];
>     }else{
>      [rootView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:searchBar
>                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
>                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
>                                                              toItem:self.view
>                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
>                                                          multiplier:1
>                                                            constant:0]];
>     }
>     [rootView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:searchBar
>                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
>                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
>                                                             toItem:rootView
>                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
>                                                         multiplier:1
>                                                           constant:0]];
>
>     [rootView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:searchBar
>                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
>                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
>                                                             toItem:rootView
>                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
>                                                         multiplier:1
>                                                           constant:0]];
>
>     [rootView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:countryTable
>                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
>                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
>                                                             toItem:searchBar
>                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
>                                                         multiplier:1
>                                                           constant:0]];
>
>     [rootView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rootView
>                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
>                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
>                                                             toItem:countryTable
>                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
>                                                         multiplier:1
>                                                           constant:0]];
>
>     [rootView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rootView
>                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
>                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
>                                                             toItem:countryTable
>                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
>                                                         multiplier:1
>                                                           constant:0]];
>
>     if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
>     [rootView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.bottomLayoutGuide
>                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
>                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
>                                                             toItem:countryTable
>                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
>                                                         multiplier:1
>                                                           constant:0]];
>     }else{
>     [rootView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
>                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
>                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
>                                                             toItem:countryTable
>                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
>                                                         multiplier:1
>                                                           constant:0]];
> ```